# Edit liquid files programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify

Can I edit in the .liquid files automatically in a shopify app instead of asking the shop owner to copy a code snippet into his template files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply download the Liquid Asset into your App, modify the file as you see fit, and then upload the edited Asset back into the Shop.

Note that people will hate you for this as any mistakes you make are not easy to fix and when people uninstall your App, those edits persist, potentially breaking the shop.

So while you think you are being nice to your customers, you are treading dangerous turf.